# Подсчитать количество элементов в массиве соответствующих условию. MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Имеются 2 коллекции: "shop" и "products".
Структура коллекций:

1. "shop"

   _id: "id",
   name: "shopName",
   products: ["someProduct", "someProduct", ...]
2. "products"

   _id: "id",
   name: "productName",
   price: someNumber

Теперь вопрос:
с помощью агрегации найти количество продуктов в каждом магазине, минимальную/максимальную/среднюю стоимость продуктов в магазине, количество продуктов со стоимостью меньше 100. Первые два пункта выполняю, а третий с условием не могу сообразить.
Это пример запроса:

```
"db.shop.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: "products",
    localField: "products",
    foreignField: "name",
    as: "products_list"}},
  {$unwind: {
    path: "$products_list"}},
  {$group: {
    _id: {name: "$name"},
    count_in_shop: {$sum: 1},
    avgprice: {$avg: "$products_list.price"},
    minprice: {$min: "$products_list.price"},
    maxprice: {$max: "$products_list.price"}}},
  {$match: {"products_list.price": {$lte: 100}}},
  {$count: "count_in_shop_less_100"}
  ])"
```

Если убрать $match и $count то всё работает, но с этими последними двумя пунктами не происходит ничего. Подскажите как быть

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй воспользоваться $sum и $cond.

```
db.shop.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
    from: "products",
    localField: "products",
    foreignField: "name",
    as: "products_list"}},
  {$unwind: {
    path: "$products_list"}},
  {$group: {
    _id: {name: "$name"},
    count_in_shop: {$sum: 1},
    avgprice: {$avg: "$products_list.price"},
    minprice: {$min: "$products_list.price"},
    maxprice: {$max: "$products_list.price"},
    count_in_shop_less_100: { $sum: { $cond: [ { $lte: ["$products_list.price", 100]}, 1, 0 ] } } }}
])
```